# Remove input_variable node from cntk model

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, cntk

I want to remove the input_variable from the model in order to make it auto_regressive (i.e. apply UnfoldFrom on it)

I have a simple example below.

```
def auto_regressive(model):
    @C.Function
    def unfold(seq_start, dyn_axis: Sequence[Tensor[121]]):
        unfoldfrom = UnfoldFrom(lambda x: model(x))
        return unfoldfrom(initial_state=seq_start, dynamic_axes_like=dyn_axis)

        return unfold

a = C.sequence.input_variable(121, name='input_tensor')  # line 1
model = Recurrence(LSTM(121, name='LSTM'), name="Recur")(a)  # line 2
# Do something to remove input_variable from model here
output_tensor = auto_regressive(model)(C.Constant(0, shape=121), a)  # line 3
```

The last line will raise an exception because in line 2 i feed input_variable a into the model. If i were to leave it out, then it will execute fine.

The reason why i need to remove the input_variable is that i have a model that has been pretrained and i want to remove the input_variable.